# Match a space between " "

Tags: regex

I want to match text that contains:
`MyValue="{NON_SPACEs}{SPACE_ONE_OE_MORE}{NON_SPACEs}"`

pattern:

> MyValue="(\S*)(\s+)(\S*)"

Example of text:

`sometext` `MyValue="val1 val2"` `sometext="xyz"`

the problem of my pattern that it's also matches:

`sometext` `MyValue="val1val2"` `sometext="xyz"`  (no space between val1 and val2)

I use this for tests: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict your non-space chars to also be non-quotes:

```
MyValue="([^\s"]*)(\s+)([^\s"]*)"
```

This regex won't try to span multiple quoted values.

Consider removing some or all of those brackets, especially around the spaces, unless you *need* to capture a group.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="abc xyz";

      string re1=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
      string re2="(\\s+)";  // White Space 1

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String ws1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+ws1.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it Helps :)

Comment: A downvote is acceptable, but with a proper explanation. Or may be I should quit helping people >:(